# how to rewrite the url from /home/index/id to home-index-id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

.net core2.1 url rewrite I want use the SEO

i use the IIS and the url like the project URL：

```
    /Home
    /Home/
    /Home/Index
    /Home/Index/Id
```

after rewrite Url:

```
    /Home
    /Home
    /Home-Index
    /Home-Index-Abc
    /Home-index-Abc?code=xxx
```

```
    var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect(@"(.*)/(.*)", "$1-$2", 302).AddRedirect(@"(.*)/(.*)/(.*)", "$1-$2-$3", 302);
                    app.UseRewriter(options);
                    app.UseMvc(routes =>
                    {
                        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default1",
                        template: "{controller=home}-{action=Index}-{par}");
                    });
                    app.UseMvc(routes =>
                    {
                        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    });
```

the `/home/` I can't visit it and it will rewrite `/home-`.help me

Answer (score 0):

From Scott Hanselman's [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCore22ParameterTransformersForCleanURLGenerationAndSlugsInRazorPagesOrMVC.aspx)

We can make an IOutboundParameterTransformer that changes URLs to a format (for example) like a WordPress standard slug in the two-words format.

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) { return null; }

        // Slugify value
        return Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
    }
}
```

Then you let the ASP.NET Pipeline know about this transformer, either in Razor Pages...

```
services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(
        new PageRouteTransformerConvention(
            new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
});
```

or in ASP.NET MVC:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(
                                 new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
});
```